# Simple run-length encoding decoder

Tags: python, python-3.x

For practice, I decided to write a [run-length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) decoder. For example:

```
basic_run_length_decode("1A2B3C")
=> 'ABBCCC'

basic_run_length_decode("5A10Z10J")
=> 'AAAAAZZZZZZZZZZJJJJJJJJJJ'
```

It ended up getting long, but that's mostly because I wanted try incorporating the [`partition-by`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partition-by) function from Clojure. It seemed like it would work nicely here, and it did. It required me to write that function though since Python doesn't seem to have anything equivalent. I also "stole" `grouper` from the ["recipe"](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) section of the `itertools` docs. Clojure has both of these functions as part of its standard library, so that's what I thought of while writing this.

Basically, it works by cutting the string into groups of digits and non-digits, pairing them into `[digits, word]` pairs, then parsing the digits and doing some string multiplication.

What I'd like commented on mainly:

- `partition_by`. I tried to see if there was a sane way of using something like `takewhile` + `drop_while`, but both of those functions consume an extra element after the predicate flips, which caused problems. I opted to just do manual iteration, but it's quite verbose.
- Anything else that I may be doing the hard way.

Note, it actually allows for multiple characters per number.

```
basic_run_length_decode("10AB10CD")
=> 'ABABABABABABABABABABCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCD'
```

I thought about raising an error, but decided to just allow it. This is apparently a type of possible encoding, and it cost me nothing to allow it.

```
from itertools import zip_longest
from typing import Callable, Any, Iterable, TypeVar, Generator, List

T = TypeVar("T")
# Emulating https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partition-by
def _partition_by(f: Callable[[T], Any], iterable: Iterable[T]) -> Generator[List[T], None, None]:
    """Splits off a new chunk everytime f returns a new value.
    list(partition_by(lambda n: n < 5, [1, 2, 3, 6, 3, 2, 1])) => [[1, 2, 3], [6], [3, 2, 1]]
    """
    last_value = object()  # Dummy object that will never be equal to anything else
    chunk = []

    for x in iterable:
        returned = f(x)

        if returned == last_value:
            chunk.append(x)

        else:
            if chunk:
                yield chunk

            chunk = [x]

        last_value = returned

    if chunk:
        yield chunk


# Recipe from https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile
def _grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    """Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"""
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)


def _invalid_encoded_error(message: str) -> ValueError:
    return ValueError(f"Invalid encoded string. {message}")


def basic_run_length_decode(encoded_string: str) -> str:
    """Decodes a string in the form of <number><chars><number><chars>. . .
    basic_run_length_decode("1A2B3C") => 'ABBCCC'"""
    if encoded_string and not encoded_string[0].isdigit():
        raise _invalid_encoded_error("First character must be a number.")

    chunks = _partition_by(lambda c: c.isdigit(), encoded_string)

    acc = []
    for raw_n, raw_word in _grouper(chunks, 2):
        if not raw_word:
            raise _invalid_encoded_error("Trailing numbers without character at end of encoded string.")

        n = int("".join(raw_n))  # Should never throw as long as the very first char is a digit?
        word = "".join(raw_word)

        acc.append(n * word)

    return "".join(acc)
```

Answer (score 5):

The code looks good to me, it is well documented and I do not have much to say.

**Suggestion for `_partition_by`**

In:

```
    if returned == last_value:
        chunk.append(x)
    else:
        if chunk:
            yield chunk
        chunk = [x]
```

I'd tried to write `chunk = [x]` as `chunk = [] ; chunk.append(x)`. This allows some rewriting as you can extract the common line out of the `if / else`.

```
    if returned == last_value:
        pass
    else:
        if chunk:
            yield chunk
        chunk = []
    chunk.append(x)
```

Then revert condition

```
    if returned != last_value:
        if chunk:
            yield chunk
        chunk = []
    chunk.append(x)
```

Then group condition as there is nothing to do when `chunk` is already empty.

```
    if chunk and returned != last_value:
        yield chunk
        chunk = []
    chunk.append(x)
```

There is nothing wrong with the way things were done, this is a pure personal preference.

**Details about docstring**

The docstrings are slightly inconsistent as we have two different forms for the verb: with and without the final 's'. If that can be of any help, there are Docstring conventions for Python in [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

It suggests:

> The docstring is a phrase ending in a period. It prescribes the
>   function or method's effect as a command ("Do this", "Return that"),
>   not as a description; e.g. don't write "Returns the pathname ...".

Answer (score 2):

Short and flexible substitution for initial **`_partition_by`** function  by using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) *magic* (to generate/split a consecutive groups by *predicate*):

```
from typing import Callable, Any, Iterable, TypeVar, Generator, List
from itertools import groupby

T = TypeVar("T")

def _partition_by(f: Callable[[T], Any], iterable: Iterable[T]) -> Generator[List[T], None, None]:
    """Splits to consecutive chunks by predicate.
    list(partition_by(lambda n: n < 5, [1, 2, 3, 6, 3, 2, 1])) => [[1, 2, 3], [6], [3, 2, 1]]
    """
    for k, group in groupby(iterable, key=f):
        yield list(group)
```

*Use case:*

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 6, 3, 2, 1]
print(list(_partition_by(lambda n: n < 5, lst)))
```

*The output:*

```
[[1, 2, 3], [6], [3, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought I tried `groupby` and it didn't do what I wanted. I think I misinterpreted it as returning a map instead of a list of pairs. Ya, looking at it now, it's basically `partition_by`.

Answer (score 2):

### Type Hint

The return type `-> Generator[List[T], None, None]` is correct, but it is a little verbose.  The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=generator#typing.Generator) suggests a simpler way of documenting generators that just yield values, using `Iterator[]`

```
def _partition_by(...) -> Iterator[List[T]]:
```

The method `_grouper()` doesn't have a return type hint.

### The Hard Way

> - Anything else that I may be doing the hard way.

Well, you are doing the whole thing The Hard Way™.

You are looking for occurrences of `<number><chars>` in a string.  This sounds like a job for the [`regular expression module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).  The `<number>` pattern is simply `(\d+)`, and the `<chars>` pattern would be characters which are not numbers, which can be expressed concisely as `(\D+)` ... using a capital letter indicates it is matching not-digit characters.

Since you wish to find successive occurrences of these, you would want to use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall), or perhaps [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer):

```
for m in re.finditer(r"(\d+)(\D+)", encoded_str)
```

Now, `m.group(1)` is the string containing `<number>` characters and `m.group(2)` is the string containing the `<chars>` character.  At this point, we can turn the digits into an integer, multiply the character string by that value, and join successive values together into one large string:

```
def basic_run_length_decode(encoded_string: str) -> str:
    """
    Decodes a string in the form of <number><chars><number><chars>. . .

    >>> basic_run_length_decode("1A2B3C")
    'ABBCCC'
    >>> basic_run_length_decode("10AB10CD")
    'ABABABABABABABABABABCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCD'
    """

    return "".join(m.group(2) * int(m.group(1))
                   for m in re.finditer(r"(\d+)(\D+)", encoded_string))
```

Yup.  Your function can be simplified to one line of code, with no helper functions.  Re-adding error checking left as exercise.  ;-)

### Doctest

I've changed the format of your `"""docstring"""` slightly.

Instead of writing:

```
    basic_run_length_decode("1A2B3C") => 'ABBCCC'
```

which implies to the reader that when you execute `basic_run_length_decode("1A2B3C")`, it will return the value `'ABBCCC'`, I've replaced this with:

```
    >>> basic_run_length_decode("1A2B3C")
    'ABBCCC'
```

which implies if you are at Python's REPL, and you type `basic_run_length_decode("1A2B3C")`, it will return the value `'ABBCCC'`, the representation of (ie, with quotes) which will be printed by the REPL.

Basically, exactly the same thing.

Except ...

The [`doctest`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/doctest.html) module knows how to read docstrings for functions, and extract things that look like Python REPL commands (ie, appear after a `>>>` prompt), and will execute those commands and compare the actual result with the indicated result, and raise an error if they don't match.  Built-in unit testing!

Let's test our code!

```
aneufeld$ python3 -m doctest run_length_decode.py
aneufeld$
```

Well, that was anticlimactic; nothing got printed.  That's a good thing.  It means the tests passed.  We can add a `-v` to make the output more verbose:

```
aneufeld$ python3 -m doctest -v run_length_decode.py 
Trying:
    basic_run_length_decode("1A2B3C")
Expecting:
    'ABBCCC'
ok
Trying:
    basic_run_length_decode("10AB10CD")
Expecting:
    'ABABABABABABABABABABCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCD'
ok
1 items had no tests:
    run_length_decode
1 items passed all tests:
   2 tests in run_length_decode.basic_run_length_decode
2 tests in 2 items.
2 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
aneufeld$
```

Comment: Thanks. Honestly, I never learned regex . I've tried several times, and I always just ended up frustrated. I can see how terse they can allow code to be though.

Comment: Funny.  I often find myself wanting to say the same thing about lambda functions, closures, and functional programming.  I can see how they can allow non-string processing code to be be terse.  